# fill rest of view in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

How do i achieve the following layout within a storyboard? I have seen related answers in SO suggesting a code solution. But can it be done codeless?

[image]

Comment: Yes it can be done codeless, but you'll still have to write code for loading container views. I have worked on similar thing, where I had a segment bar on the top of fixed height and container view on the rest of the view controller, this might be of some help to you. Let me know if you still have any questions.
https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your toolbar at the top set the left, right, and top spacing constraints with a constant of 0, then set a height constraint with a constant of whatever your fixed height is.

For the bottom container view, set the left, right, and bottom spacing constraints with a constant of 0, and set a vertical spacing constraint to the toolbar, also with a constant of 0.

This will anchor the toolbar to the top and automatically fill the rest of your view controller with the container view.